# JDesktopPane.setOpaque(false) plus use of JInternalFrame inhibits closing of containing JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Java 1.8.0_60 on Linux. A JFrame is created, a JDesktopPane set as its content pane and used for displaying some line graphics plus JInternalFrames at arbitrary positions. It seems that certain calls, or locations of calls result in a state where the JFrame cannot be destroyed by clicking at the "x".

These are the classes; not the comments "X1" and "X2".

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class InternalFrameEventDemo extends JFrame {
  public InternalFrameEventDemo(String title) {
    super(title);
    JDesktopPane desktop = new MyDesktop();
    this.setContentPane(desktop);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
  }

  private class MyDesktop extends JDesktopPane {
    public MyDesktop(){
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,300));
    }
    public void paintComponent( Graphics sg ) {
        super.paintComponent( sg );
        new StarLabel( this, 100, 100, "Here at 100" );  // X1
        new StarLabel( this, 200, 200, "Here at 200" );
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new InternalFrameEventDemo("InternalFrameEventDemo");
        }
    });
  }
}
```

### `StarLabel`

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class StarLabel extends JInternalFrame {
  public StarLabel( JComponent panel, int x, int y, String text ) {
    super( null, false, true, false, false );
    this.setBorder( null );
    ((javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI) this.getUI()).setNorthPane(null);
    this.setVisible( true );
    this.setOpaque( false );  // X2
    this.add( new JLabel( text ) );
    this.pack();
    this.setLocation( x, y );
    panel.add( this );
  }
}
```

X1: The effect remains absent if the StarLabel constructor calls aren't made in `paintComponent`.

X2: The effect also does not occur if setOpaque is not set to false.

Now I can use setOpaque with true - the false was pure chance. But I'd still like to know whether I an violating one of the rules in the small print? Or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I'd still like to know whether I an violating one of the rules in the small print?

Yes.

> The effect remains absent if the StarLabel constructor calls aren't made in paintComponent.

A painting method is for painting only.

You should NEVER create a Swing component in a painting method. You can't control when the painting method is invoked so you will be creating new components every time Swing determines the component needs to be created.

The components should be created in the constructor of your class.

Comment: The plan is to have these JInternalFrames created dynamically due to user interactions, which should be OK. Placing them unconditionally was just a dry run. But creating them in an event callback shouldn't be a problem.